# XSL Namespace Misunderstanding

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am just dipping my toes into XML and XSL, and (from what I have read, unsurprisingly) I am having issues with name-space.

I have been given some XML, and I am trying to write some XSL, however I am having issues accessing some of the namespaces and attributes etc...

Here is an extract from the XML I have been given...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2 
           http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd" 
         version="1.2" 
         date="2013-06-24" 
         time="01:35:45" 
         readOnly="false" 
         language="English">
  <Units>
    <Metric linearUnit="meter" areaUnit="squareMeter" 
            volumeUnit="cubicMeter" 
            angularUnit="decimal dd.mm.ss" 
            latLongAngularUnit="decimal degrees" 
            temperatureUnit="celsius" 
            pressureUnit="milliBars"/>
  </Units>
  <CoordinateSystem name="HATCH-121204" 
    horizontalDatum="Local" 
    verticalDatum="Local" 
    ellipsoidName="Australian National" 
    projectedCoordinateSystemName="UTM55" 
    fileLocation="">
  </CoordinateSystem>
  <Application name="LandXML Export" 
    manufacturer="Leica Geosystems AG" 
    version="4.3" 
    manufacturerURL="www.leica-geosystems.com">
    <Author company="Leica Geosystems AG" 
      companyURL="www.leica-geosystems.com" 
      timeStamp="2013-06-24T01:35:45"/>
  </Application>
  <CgPoints>
    <CgPoint name="GPS0093" 
             oID="GPS0093" 
             code="728" 
             desc="Tel 
             lines u/g" 
             role="measured" 
             latitude="-21.968945617359" longitude="148.007359609463" 
             ellipsoidHeight="288.420425" 
             timeStamp="2013-06-22T01:55:26"
    >7570087.642555 603892.199974 234.579968</CgPoint>
...
...
...
```

I am trying to access: LandXML/CgPoint/CgPoints, here is the XSL that I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="130622RLA.xml" -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.5">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <head>
        <title>Field Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="books2_xslt.css"/>
        <p class="header">Field Report</p>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CgPoints/CgPoint"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CgPoint">        
    In CgPoints
    <xsl:for-each select="@name">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        HELLO CgPoint
      </xsl:for-each>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For some reason I never get into the "CgPoint" template (I never get the "In CgPoints" html output). I have tried all sorts of combinations of "LandXML/CgPoints/CgPoint",  "CgPoints/CgPoint" etc in the call and the template definition.

Does anyone have any insight into where my misunderstanding stems from?

Thanks in advance,

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are bound to the namespace `http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2`.

Usually, you would declare the namespace in your XSLT with a namespace-prefix and use that to address them in the `@select` and `@match` criteria:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="130622RLA.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.5"
    xmlns:land="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <head>
                <title>Field Report</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="books2_xslt.css"/>
                <p class="header">
                    Field Report</p>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/land:CgPoints/land:CgPoint"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="land:CgPoint">      
        In CgPoints
        <xsl:for-each select="@name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            HELLO CgPoint
        </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also use a generic match on the elements with a predicate filter for the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`: `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='CgPoint' and namespace-uri()='http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2']">`, but that is extremely verbose and tedious.

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, you also have two other options

1.) Use a wildcard for the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="130622RLA.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.5">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <head>
                <title>Field Report</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="books2_xslt.css"/>
                <p class="header">
                    Field Report</p>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*:CgPoints/*:CgPoint"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:CgPoint">      
        In CgPoints
        <xsl:for-each select="@name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            HELLO CgPoint
        </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2.) Use `xpath-default-namespace` (as Max Toro suggested)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="130622RLA.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.5"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <head>
                <title>Field Report</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="books2_xslt.css"/>
                <p class="header">
                    Field Report</p>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/CgPoints/CgPoint"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CgPoint">      
        In CgPoints
        <xsl:for-each select="@name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            HELLO CgPoint
        </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Mads, this has helped solve my problem, and has given me a better insight on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath-default-namespace`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xpath-default-namespace="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2">
   ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick response. Tried out what you suggested, but I the output remains the same :(

Comment: @user2514675 - Try changing `<xsl:template match="/">` to `<xsl:template match="/*">`. In XSLT, context is everything.

Comment: Or adjust the apply-templates to: `<xsl:apply-templates select="*/CgPoints/CgPoint"/>`

Comment: Still no luck with either of these. Lee

Comment: If you tried the two suggestions separately, they won't work; you need both.  The xpath-default-namespace to make your match patterns work, the change to the select pattern that selects CgPoint to make the selection work.  If you apply both of them correctly, it should work; if it doesn't work, you haven't applied both corrections correctly.